# Create custom validators for the dynamically added form controls in angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular6

[image]I am new to angular development and I am stuck at a point where I need to perform the validation on the dynamically added rows.

I use template-driven forms. I have two fields ValidFrom and ValidTo and an array of blackout dates `{fromdate and todate}`. The model is below

```
export interface Rooms {
   validFrom?: Date | string;
   validTo?: Date | string;
  blackOutDateVM?: BlackOutDateVM[];

}

export class BlackOutDateVM {
    validFrom?: Date;
    validTo?: Date;
}
```

Currently, I use this function when the user is going to submit the form to validate the dates.

```
 ValidateRateForDatesAndTax(): boolean {

     this.isFormValid = true;    

    if (this.rateDetail.isContainsBlackOutDates === true) {
      this.rateDetail.blackOutDateVM.forEach(item => {
        if (item.validFrom < item.validTo) {
          this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = false;
        } else {
          this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = true;
        }

        if (item.validFrom === null || item.validFrom === undefined) {
          this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = false;
          this.isFormValid = false;
        } else {
          this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = true;
        }

        if (item.validTo === null || item.validTo === undefined) {
          this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = false;
          this.isFormValid = false;
        } else {
          this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = true;
        }

        if (
          item.validFrom === null ||
          item.validFrom === undefined ||
          (item.validTo === null || item.validTo === undefined)
        ) {
          if (
            item.validFrom > this.rateDetail.validTo ||
            item.validTo < this.rateDetail.validFrom
          ) {
            this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = false;
            this.isFormValid = false;
          } else {
            this.rateValidator.isBlackOutDatesValid = true;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    return this.isFormValid;
  }
```

I want to make sure that blackout dates should be within the valid from and valid to dates. Can anyone let me know how to perform this validation in angular?

Comment: You want to validate this through the view (directly on the template) or in your component ts?

Comment: I want to validate this through UI, like creating directives ...

Comment: Okay can you show us what's your UI right now to help you through the part you are stuck it?

Comment: attached the screenshot, please review it.

Comment: Please share use the code, you have tried so far. So others could solve your problem

Comment: @BearNithi : Shared the code in the comment

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use form builder service of angular,

So let me suggest you how you should go about doing this,

1. Create FormBuilder by importing, injecting in constructor,
2. Write a custom validation function such that it acts like you would write a function onchange event

   `yourValidationFunctionFrom(){}`
   `yourValidationFunctionTo(){}`
3. create a form instance (if this is required)

   ```
   `this.yourForm = this._fb.group({
         BlackOutDate: this._fb.array([this.fb.control('From',[yourValidationFunctionFrom]),
   ```

   this.fb.control('To',[yourValidationFunctionTo])])
           });`

Using form builder you can do a lot of operation a lot easily, you will be surprised that angular has so much packed in it for our help

Comment: I use template driven forms... @Deepak Can you let me know whether the same is achievable using template driven forms or not ?